# List of table names ordered by their foreign key dependency in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given a MySQL database, how do I obtain a list of table names ordered by their foreign key dependency so that I can delete each table?  I understand that the foreign key's are stored in the `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table but I'm not sure if there is a utility method to obtain the table names in the correct order. I would prefer a 100% SQL solution.

Comment: Why don't you want to delete all database then?

Comment: This essentially treats the tables as a hierarchy based on the FK dependencies, so see http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

If your foreign keys follow a naming convention (as they should :), then you could do something simple like

```
select table_name, group_concat(distinct constraint_name order by constraint_name) as fk_list
from   information_schema.key_column_usage
where  constraint_name rlike 'fk'
group  by table_name
order  by fk_list, table_name;
```

Or, if your foreign keys don't follow a naming convention, then

```
select table_name, group_concat(distinct constraint_name order by constraint_name) as fk_list
from   information_schema.key_column_usage
where  referenced_table_name is not null
group  by table_name
order  by fk_list, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getDependencyOrder`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare _id int;
    declare _name varchar(50);
    declare _refname varchar(50);

    declare cur cursor for
        select table_name, referenced_table_name
        from   information_schema.key_column_usage
        where  constraint_schema = 'your_schema_name';/*************/

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    drop table if exists temp;
    create temporary table temp (id int, tablename varchar(50)) engine=memory;

    open cur;

    set _id = 1000000;

    REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO _name, _refname;
        IF NOT done THEN
            if not exists(select * from temp where tablename = _name) then
                insert into temp(id, tablename) values(_id, _name);
                set _id = _id + 1000;
            end if;
        end if;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur;

    set done = 0;

    open cur;
    REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO _name, _refname;
        IF NOT done THEN
            if not (_refname is null) then
                if _name <> _refname then
                    #Buscar el id de la tabla
                    select id into @Id from temp where tablename = _name;
                    #Buscar el id de la tabla de referencia, si su id es mayor, ajustar su id
                    select id into @refId from temp where tablename = _refname;

                    if @refId > @Id then
                        select max(id) + 1000 into _id from temp where id < @Id;

                        if _id is null then
                            select min(id) - 1000 into _id from temp;
                        end if;

                        if exists(select * from temp where id = _id) then
                            select max(id) into @max from temp where id < @Id;
                            set _id = (@max + @Id) / 2;
                        end if;

                        update temp set id = _id where id = @refId;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur;

    select * from temp order by id;

    drop table temp;
END
```

Comment: Be sure to change 'your_schema_name' by the name of your schema, apply changes and: call getDependencyOrder();

Comment: If your schema have a huge amount of tables, you can change the type of the variable '_id' and the type of the field 'id' in the temporary table to be a floating point type instead of int. The important thing here is the order of the tables, not the id.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do, I hope it might work for you as well:

`SELECT t.TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
RIGHT JOIN information_schema.Tables t
    ON t.TABLE_NAME=kcu.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA='<name_of_your_schema>' GROUP BY t.TABLE_NAME ORDER BY t.TABLE_TYPE DESC, COUNT(TRUE) DESC;`

Selects tables ordered by their dependency count, most dependant tables will appear first, least dependant will appear last. Notice I ask for views before all, because, they're usually more dependant on tables than other tables, but they don't usually have any foreign keys.